# How to read excel file column data which comes from formula using Apache Spark

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, spark-excel

I am trying to read the one excel file in spark. I am using `crealytics` library for this.

But my code is getting failed as one of the column is referring sheet to populate its value through **VLOOKUP** formula.

I have been trying with "crealytics" library but no luck.

```
val df = spark.read.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
        .option("sheetName", "Final_Output")
        .option("useHeader", "true")
        .option("treatEmptyValuesAsNulls", "false")
        .option("inferSchema", "false")
        .option("addColorColumns", "false")
        .option("location", input_path)
        .load()

df.show(5, false)
```

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown cell type 2 for VLOOKUP.

Comment: Your exception is not coming due to calculated columns. Spark does not distinguish between calculated columns and normal columns.

Comment: One more thing I would like to mention- use have defined 'inferSchema' as false and you are not providing any schema explicitly.

Comment: there is very nice example available on https://github.com/crealytics/spark-excel.